# Programmatically inherit a table in C# windows form application

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer

Things are graceful in DataGridView but i wanted to learn how i can inherit a table and do re-factor it for each data item fetched from the SQLite database?
I have designed a table`(System.Windows.Forms.Table)` using the Visual Studio 2013 Designer, pretty much it was a drag-n-drop design.
The table has two column, left most column show's the data fetched from the SQLite database also it has a child table`(System.Windows.Forms.Table)` which has two row *(table row)* where each row *(table row)* has a textField which actually show to different database row *(this is the database row)* value. 
The right one has some buttons to trigger few events.
Here is how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Lfd.png 
[image]

Now my question is, in this environment how i can inherit this table design and create multiple instances `foreach` data rows comes from its SQLite database file?

**Demonstration:** Here is a quick demonstration of what i wanted to achieve.
Assume that the database table called "lists" has four items, so this application would create four instances of this table(Windows form table), insert all the data in appropriate fields in the table(Windows form table) and list them in the "Form1" form, something look like this [ *did it on photoshop* ;) ]
[image]

Please direct me in the right path by giving your idea and references

Comment: Would a user control work for you?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171926.aspx

Comment: Many thanks GER for you response earlier, this is me right now https://33.media.tumblr.com/0b11ea8029966fbd80b4699ea6c757d0/tumblr_mew7zbIJtX1qfs7v6o1_250.gif :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I worked in WinForms, but the concept is similar in all of the DotNet UI methodologies based upon the question from GER on the original post.

If you define a UserControl that renders the data to look like a single instance of what you have in your photo-shopped item, you can then reuse that control several times.

In your main form, you can now do a loop to add this control as many times as you need programmatically (psuedo code follows at the end).

You will also need a TableLayoutPanel (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or similar for your primary form to serve as the layoutPanel.

```
foreach(DataTable table in Tables)
{
    MyChildControl childControl = new MyChildControl();
    childControl.Confiure(table); // Sets the data for the control.
    layoutPanel.Controls.Add(childControl); // This call varies by UI method and what layoutPanel you are using
}
```

Caveat: I can't remember enough about WinForms to remember how to set the grid row/column settings on the control. You get to do some research on that one if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin i'm so exited having the solution :) https://33.media.tumblr.com/0b11ea8029966fbd80b4699ea6c757d0/tumblr_mew7zbIJtX1qfs7v6o1_250.gif

Comment: Glad to hear it. :) Programmatic UIs add some complexity in how you have to think about the design, but also gain lots of control at run-time for customization.